# Is it possible to create a SOCKS chain using PLink on Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, networking, proxy, plink

I've been trying to create a chain of SOCKS proxies using the Dynamic Port parameter of PLink/PuTTy, but to no success. I'm currently trying to chain from my Windows machine using PLink/PuTTy > Linux Box 1 > Linux Box 2. Is this possible whilst keeping TCP_NODELAY/Nagle's Algorithm Disabled?

I am doing this to route game traffic through the SOCKS proxy using a proxifier. Unfortunately if I don't use PLink/PuTTy and use the proxifier's built-in ability to forward directly to SOCKS proxies hosted on my Linux Boxes, it suffers from Nagle's Algorithm (causing insanely high latency).

Any ideas or suggestions would be really helpful. Thank you!

EDIT: I also tried/thought of something like this: Having all traffic coming into Linux Box 1 go to Linux Box 2 (via. something like a proxy) and I continue to have a single dynamic socks proxy connection from my Windows Box (PLink) > Linux Box 1. But when I tried something like this, the incoming traffic from my Windows machine didn't get tunneled through to Linux Box 2."

Answer (score 1):

*(Posting the solution that OP edited into the question)*

Solved! The issue I was actually having was that the port wasn't forwarded on the Box x.x even though I had a rule forwarding ALL ports, it got overwritten by "block all but these". The command line I used is something like this:

```
plink.exe {Box 2} -P 22 -C -L 127.0.0.1:444:{Box 3}:3389 -l username -pw password
```

Thanks everyone!